asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending
I have a uvicorn + fast API server that serves a simple get request

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

async def main():
    logger.info("Running")
    config = uvicorn.Config(
        "sagemaker.app:app",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=9007,
        log_level="info",
        loop="asyncio",
        reload=True,
        workers=3,
        use_colors=True,
    )
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    logger.info("I'm just waiting for a connection")
    await server.serve()

In the same application im trying to check if the get request works
I start serving here

    def _start_serving(self):
        asyncio.create_task(main())

        time.sleep(10)

in a different callback i try to ping the local host
    async def tcp_connect(self):
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 9007)
        logger.debug(reader)
        writer.write(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:9007\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n')
        logger.debug(writer.get_extra_info('peername'))
        logger.debug(writer.transport)

        data = await reader.readline()
        logger.info(data)
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()

In my notebook i am not able to read the response back from the server
INFO:app:Running
WARNING:  "workers" flag is ignored when reloading is enabled.
INFO:sagemaker.app:I'm just waiting for a connection
INFO:     Started server process [90207]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:9007 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
ERROR:asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-9' coro=<InProcessMultiModelServer.tcp_connect() done, defined at  wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
INFO:     127.0.0.1:47876 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK


I do see this in the client logs

DEBUG:     <StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=64 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>>
DEBUG:     ('127.0.0.1', 9007)
DEBUG:     <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=64 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>

Tried adding a strong reference.
    #background_tasks = set()
    asyncio.create_task(self.tcp_connect())
    #background_tasks.add(task)
    #task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)

